# Regex: Parse out lines

Tags: php, regex, parsing, lines

I'm writing a system which can make daily schedules based on schedule mails we get at McDonald's. It's a request from my boss. I'm doing this in PHP.

The mails we get are as following:

> Beste HIDE,
>
> Hier is je rooster voor de week van 16-7-2012:
>
> maandag 16 juli 2012 17:00 - 23:00, KEU
>   dinsdag 17 juli 2012 11:30 - 19:15, COU
>   woensdag 18 juli 2012 16:30 - 23:00, KEU
>
> In totaal ben je 20,25 uur ingeroosterd, 3 shifts and 0 sluitdiensten.
>
> Voor vragen of vrijvraagverzoeken kun je me bereiken via: rooster.1197@nl.mcd.com.
>
> Ben je verkeerd ingeroosterd en heb je wel goed vrijgevraagd, of wil je meer werken? Mail dan naar rooster.1197@nl.mcd.com! Ik ga dan kijken wat ik voor je kan doen.
>
> Let op! Komende weken moeten er een aantal mensen naar de drive toe! Achter je dienst staat dan DRI. Het is de bedoeling dat iedereen daar af en toe een dienst gaat werken zodat iedereen genoeg uren kan krijgen.  Dit betekend dus dat iedereen maximaal 1x per week in de drive wordt geroosterd. Jullie dienen op eigen vervoer te gaan. Dit geldt ook voor de nachtdiensten in de drive. Er worden altijd groepjes gestuurd dus spreek met elkaar af.
>
> Groeten,
>
> HIDE

I want to parse out the following lines:

```
maandag 16 juli 2012 17:00 - 23:00, KEU
dinsdag 17 juli 2012 11:30 - 19:15, COU
woensdag 18 juli 2012 16:30 - 23:00, KEU
```

So I can loop trough them..

How would I do this, I thought by using a regex but I don't know how..

Swen

Comment: Are you sure that pattern of `string | date | duration |, KEU` won't be used out of this context?

Comment: the format is as following, and it's always the same:
day [space] date [space] month [space] year [space] time [space] - [space] time, station

Comment: And yes the emails do not change

Comment: Can you show us what you have done? Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[a-z]*\s[0-9]{1,2}[a-z]*\s[a-z]*\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s-\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},\s[a-z]*`

Test: http://regexr.com?31fqr :)

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You might first of all extract all tokens like that one with a simpler regex:

```
    $day  = "maandag|dinsdag|woensdag|othertag|andtag|sotag|ontag";
    $reg  = "#($day) (\d+) (\w+) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+) - (\d+):(\d+), (\w+)#smi";
    $days = preg_match_all($reg, $text, $items, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    print_r($items);
```

Every $item[] will be in the form:

```
    (
        [0] => maandag 16 juli 2012 17:00 - 23:00, KEU
        [1] => maandag
        [2] => 16
        [3] => juli
        [4] => 2012
        [5] => 17
        [6] => 00
        [7] => 23
        [8] => 00
        [9] => KEU
    )
```

So you will be able to use the various elements as you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$str = 'Beste HIDE,

Hier is je rooster voor de week van 16-7-2012:

maandag 16 juli 2012 17:00 - 23:00, KEU
dinsdag 17 juli 2012 11:30 - 19:15, COU
 woensdag 18 juli 2012 16:30 - 23:00, KEU

In totaal ben je 20,25 uur ingeroosterd, 3 shifts and 0 sluitdiensten.

Voor vragen of vrijvraagverzoeken kun je me bereiken via: rooster.1197@nl.mcd.com.

  ....';

$data = explode("\n", $str);
echo $data[4].'<br/>'.$data[5].'<br/>'.$data[6];

?>
```

Try this...

Comment: +1 for doing the job without the overhead of regex.. Ofcourse it will work only if the format of $str remains same. Which it will, as stated by OP.

Comment: We can use file handling to read data from file and storing it in a string... rest functionality is same.